# Crear un procedimiento almacenado que reciba como parámetro de entrada un año

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Buenas Tardes tengo las siguientes duda,
Necesito crear un procedimiento almacenado que reciba como parámetro de entrada un año y devuelva el medicamento con mayor cantidad vendida en ese año. He intentado varias opciones pero me sale error, alguna idea de como hacerlo, gracias

Tabla1:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DELIVERY(
COD_DEL CHAR (5) NOT NULL,
COD_REP CHAR (5) NOT NULL,
FEC_DEL DATE,
EST_DEL VARCHAR (10))
```

Tabla2:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MEDICAMENTO(
COD_MED CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
NOM_MED VARCHAR(50) NULL,
COD_LAB CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PRECIO_LISTA  DECIMAL (6,2) NOT NULL,
FEC_VEN DATE NULL)
```

Comment: Hola Gustavo. Dices "He intentado varias opciones"; puedes mostrarnos lo que has intentado? Tal vez has estado muy cerca de la solución y hay que hacer ajustes mínimos. Así no andamos adivinando, y la pregunta no parece del tipo "tengo esta tarea, háganla".

Comment: Primero hice la sentencia uniendo las dos tablas para ver si me regresaba los valores que necesito y si funcionó:

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx. Podrías por favor indicar en qué motor de BD haces esto? Puedes usar una etiqueta para ello

Comment: Hola! Más allá del stored procedure, no veo que exista relación entre las 2 tablas, ¿acaso COD_REP de la tabla DELIVERY es COD_MED de la tabla MEDICAMENTO?